# sql server rank using keywords

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains Bank ID (not unique) and Bank names in a table. If the bank name contains keyword 'bank' I want to rank it one and if it 
has 'financial' rank it two and 'Trust' gets a rank of three.

```
 Create table dbo.banknames(id int null,bankname varchar(200) null)
 insert into dbo.bankname(1,'U.S. Trust')
 insert into dbo.bankname(1,'Bank of america')
 insert into dbo.bankname(1,'BOA Financial services')
 insert into dbo.bankname(2,'Citizens trust')
 insert into dbo.bankname(3,'People''s bank trust')
 insert into dbo.bankname(3,'People''s financial service')
```

The output should look like

```
Create table dbo.ExpectedOUTPUTbanknames(id int null,bankname varchar(200) null,rank int null)
insert into dbo.ExpectedOUTPUTbankname(1,'U.S. Trust',3)
insert into dbo.ExpectedOUTPUTbankname(1,'Bank of america',1)
insert into dbo.ExpectedOUTPUTbankname(1,'BOA Financial services',2)
insert into dbo.ExpectedOUTPUTbankname(2,'Citizens trust',3)
insert into dbo.ExpectedOUTPUTbankname(3,'People''s bank trust',1)
insert into dbo.ExpectedOUTPUTbankname(3,'People''s financial service',2)

select * 
into dbo.OUTPUTbankname
(
SELECT *,1 as RNK FROM  dbo.banknames
    WHERE (bankname LIKE '%bank%')
    UNION
    SELECT *,1 as RNK FROM  dbo.banknames
    WHERE (bankname LIKE '%financial%')
    UNION
    SELECT *,1 as RNK FROM  dbo.banknames
    WHERE (bankname LIKE '%trust%')
) qrey
```

For bankid =3, since bankname has both keywords bank and trust, I get 3 rows, 'People''s bank trust' with rank=1 'People''s financial service'with rank=2
'People''s bank trust' with rank=3. How can i avoid this

Thanks
MR

Comment: What happens if a back contain mulitple keywords?

Comment: It has to pick the highest. If bank name has "bank and trust" it has to be ranked 1 because it has 'bank' keyword

Comment: Then the answer I gave you below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT id,
       bankname,
       CASE WHEN bankname LIKE '%[Bb]ank%'      THEN 1
            WHEN bankname LIKE '%[Ff]inancial%' THEN 2
            WHEN bankname LIKE '%[Tt]rust%'     THEN 3
       END AS rank
FROM dbo.banknames
```

Fortunately SQL Server supports character ranges in its `LIKE` expressions, making it easy to match the keywords regardless of whether the first letter be capitalized or not.